# How do I load a .shp file using a button with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, python-addin

I have created a Python addin where the user should be able to select a shapefile and then load, but I've not been able to put in the current workspace.

```
import arcpy
import pythonaddins
import os
from arcpy import env as path
from arcpy import mapping


path = r"D:\MedellinPython"

class ButtonCarga(object):
"""Implementation for entregaFinal_addin.objButtonCarga (Button)"""
def __init__(self):
    self.enabled = True
    self.checked = False
def onClick(self):

    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "*")[0]
    addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(path)
    arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, addLayer)

class ComboShp(object):
"""Implementation for entregaFinal_addin.objComboShp (ComboBox)"""
def __init__(self):
    self.value = "Seleccione archivo .shp"
    self.items = []
    self.editable = True
    self.enabled = True
    self.dropdownWidth = 'WWWWWWWWWWWW'
    self.width = 'WWWWWWWWWWWW'
def onSelChange(self, selection):
    pass
def onEditChange(self, text):
    pass
def onFocus(self, focused):
    objComboShp.enabled = True
    self.items = []
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        if file.endswith(".shp"):
            self.items.append(file)
def onEnter(self):
    pass
def refresh(self):
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

After adding the layer in onClick try a refresh of Table of Contents. (edited after comment)

```
def onClick(self):

    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "*")[0]
    addLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(ComboShp.value)
    arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, addLayer)
    arcpy.RefreshTOC()
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I already did it but unfortunately still don't work.

Comment: Let's think about the logic of the toolbar you created. There is a button to load a Layer. And you have a comboBox to let the user select a Dataset from a predifined directory. Say, the user selects on of the datasets from the comboBox, then in onClick you have to choose that selection from the comboBox. But that is not in your code! You just use the variable path, and thats a directory, not a dataset!